# Selecting only models with related models or descendants that have related models

Tags: php, sql, activerecord, yii

So, there are categories and products, and I need to select the categories that are not empty in order to build the product categories menu.
Not empty means that the category either contains products or a descendant category contains products. I wanted to do it with a scope, but I can't seem to be getting far.

Something kind of like the following, but i need to recursively check more levels down the categories' hierarchy

```
/**
 * This is the model class for table "shopCategories".
 *
 * The followings are the available columns in table 'shop_categories':
 * @property integer $id
 * @property integer $parentId
 * @property integer $order
 * @property integer $isActive
 * @property integer $cstamp
 * @property integer $mstamp
 *
 * The followings are the available model relations:
 * @property ProductCategory $parent
 * @property ProductCategory[] $children
 * @property ProductCategoryL10n[] $l10n
 * @property ProductCategoriesProducts[] $productsJunction
 */
class ProductCategory extends BogoActiveRecord
{
...

public function nonEmpty()
{    
    $this->getDbCriteria()->mergeWith(array(
        'with' => array(
            'children',
            'children.products'=>array(
                'condition'=>'products.isActive=1',
                'joinType'=>'INNER JOIN', 'limit'=>1
            ),
        ),
    ));

    return $this;
}

...
}
```

Comment: underneath the framework abstraction, you can't "see" the sql problem if you're unfamiliar with yii I guess

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Recursion is something databases are really not good at (e.g. MySql does not support recursion at all). Unfortunately, what you ask for is not possible directly.

Your options are:

1. Do the filtering in PHP.
2. Modify your database schema to use [modified preorder tree traversal](http://mikehillyer.com/articles/managing-hierarchical-data-in-mysql/) (MPTT), update your models and ask again.

Comment: so, if i wanted to do it for a set of categories that can only go as deep as 3 levels i could do it but only by writing the whole explicit query for every level? looks bad...

Comment: @dimvic: Because the schema you have is not meant to be used like this. In your shoes I 'd simply do it in PHP.

Comment: I was not intending to use it like this by any means, but I'm "forced" to do this now... thank you for your feedback

Answer (score 0):

If you have a set limit of levels down to the products then you could build a one time query to save time on processing in PHP. You can manually do the "recursion" by adding as many joins as required back to the same table using aliases.

If your forced into your current schema then this might avoid have to rebuild the query let alone execute and abstract it back into Active Records just to see if they're empty.

This is assuming you don't have an infinitely deep menu structure.

Comment: I actually do have that, 3 levels max, and I already had an "isActive" column on the category table. What I did in the end was make a script to be ran once in a while which goes through categories, recalculates that isActive boolean field to true or false taking into account both user desired state and if the category is empty or not